# Does Windows 8 have gestures for tablet?

Tags: windows-8, tablet

On Windows 8 tablets such as Surface, is it possible to use gestures? The first one that comes to mind is an equivalent of the back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a article detailing gestures for a different tablet(Kupa X11)

> http://liliputing.com/2012/03/list-of-windows-8-touch-based-gestures.html

### Summarized

1. Swipe from the right (Charms menu)
2. Swipe from the left (Switch apps)
3. Swipe slowly from the left (Snap apps)
4. Swipe from left-and-back (Show running apps)
5. Pull down from the top (Close app)
6. Swipe down (Bring up additional menus)
7. Swipe down on an item (Select)
8. Pinch (Zoom)
9. Swipe left/right in Internet Explorer (Move back, forward)

Answer (score 2):

These are some of the new Windows 8 Touch Gestures.

[image]

Source: [Windows 8 Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/collaborating-to-deliver-windows-rt-pcs)

Answer (score 1):

- **Swipe from the right** to open the Charms bar
- **Swipe from top or bottom** to open the app's menu
- **Swipe from the left** to switch between recent apps
- **Swipe from the left into the screen and back out** to open a list of open Modern apps
- **Swipe from the left and hold, then let go** to dock a recent app at the side of the screen
- **Swipe from the very top to the very bottom of the screen** to close a Modern app

Of course, the usual stuff like pinch to zoom and swiping to scroll works in most apps depending on context like you would expect.